# Authenticate the token against multiple 'Client Id' from same Tenant : Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Is it possible to authenticate the user token against multiple 'Client Id' from the same tenant ?
Here is the configuration which uses the same 'ValidAudience' for Client Id.

```
  app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
            new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters { ValidAudience = B2b_ClientId },
                Tenant = B2b_Tenant,
                Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                {

                }
            });
```

Comment: `ValidAudiences`?

Comment: @juunas I want valid audience from multiple application client id's